# Limitar una hoja CSS externa a un solo div

Tags: html, css, css3

Si a la hora de diseñar mi pagina me encuentro con que para utilizar alguna libreria externa de javascript, como podria ser una galeria de imagenes carousel, esta necesita implementar una hoja de estilos CSS, pero estos estilos hacen que se modifiquen otros aspectos de la pagina, como puedo hacer para facilmente limitar toda esa hoja a un solo div, sin modificar todos y cada uno de los selectores de la hoja? Pregunto esto porque me paso que dos librerias externas, cada una necesitaba linkar una hoja CSS propia, pero estas se pisaban entre si, generando asi un mal funcionamiento de los plugins.

Answer (score 0):

En el componente genérico del primer plugin ponle un identificador o clase que sea distinto del que le pongas al segundo plugin.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<div class="plugin-generico-uno"/>
<div class="plugin-generico-dos"/>
```

Ahora solo tienes que modificar el archivo .css de cada plugin para que solo afecte al ámbito suyo, creando un envoltorio.

**CSS PLUGIN 1**

```
.plugin-generico-uno{
  // el contenido css que este plugin tenía antes
}
```

Lo mismo para el plugin 2.

Comment: Eso no se puede hacer en css, no puedes anidar selectores. Podría hacerlo en Sass  u otro preprocesador pero no en CSS puro

Comment: Cierto, estaba pensando en Sass